# Positioning images in Grid that have different sizes - with some overflowing into other cells

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a `Grid` which will hold four images. The images themselves will be the same size, but the visual part of the image can/will be different (so part of the images will be transparent).

I want the transparent parts of the images to overflow into other cells of the grid.

I also have hit tests on the grid. One for pointer-hover and one for pressed.

How can I get these images in the grid and maintain the overflow and also the hit tests?

So far my solution is to have something like 9 columns, then:

- the first image takes columns 0 to 2,
- the 2nd image takes 2 to 4,
- the 3rd images 4 to 6,
- the 4th images takes 6 to 8.

This way the images overflow. The problem though is that when each subsequent image is added, it goes on top of the shared column, so any mouse hover goes with that.

In WPF you could derive from `Image` to override `HitTestCore`; with Metro you can't do that. My plan was to hit test only non-transparent pixels.

If I can get the hit tests sorted, I can get this method working. Though if there's another/better solution, I'm all ears?

Comment: Why don't you use Canvas ? With your explainations, I assume that your grid dimensions is fixed.

Comment: I wanted to keep with a panel so when resolution changes, everything fits correctly. I guess I could manually calculate X and Y values based on the screen size, I'd just rather not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went for was to overlay the grid that contained all the images with another grid containing rectangles with the sizes I desired. I could then use the rectangles as hit tests, rather than the underlying images.

Answer (score 0):

According [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994936.aspx) for Metro Style Apps :

> Image and MediaElement controls are hit testable over their defined rectangle, regardless of transparent content.

So I don't think it's achievable with Metro this way. Note that my previous comment (Canvas) seems to not work (regarding the link below), either.